# <comp:fileUpload> supporing jar file?

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I have use the following tag. But i don't know the jar file. i want to add that jar in my project.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/taglib" prefix="comp"%>
```

and tag :

```
<comp:fileUpload value="#{uploadBean.uploadedFile}"
uploadIcon=""
uploadOnMouseOver=""
uploadOnMouseOut=""
styleClass=""
progressBarStyleClass=""
cellStyleClass=""
activeStyleClass=""/>
```

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read here: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/09/file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jsf.html

Comment: @JoseK: you should have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This tag lib does not exist.

You have to code it as per the guidelines given at
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/09/file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jsf.html